# Bug in rails with select input?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Tabindex does not work on select when using Rails. Is this a bug or am I just slow? I used "the Google" but that didn't turn up any answers, just people with similar questions.

```
<%= p.label :sector, "Sector" %>
<%= p.select :sector, [["Technology","tech"],["Healthcare","health"]], { :tabindex => 1 } %>
```

(I tried hacking this by putting the tabIndex on the label, but Chrome as an example doesn't seem to pick that up even when the output has a label "for" that matches the id of the select.)

Comment: When you think that you have found a bug in the framework, you can be 99.9% certain that it's actually you coding something wrong.

Comment: Very true. Only reason is I keep finding browser bugs in IE...of course, it's IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` (as you have it) accepts four arguments, the method, the choices, a hash for the select options, then a hash for the html attributes.  You've put the html attribute hash in position 3 instead of position 4.  Instad you want to pass in an empty hash in position 3, and your tabindex in position 4, ie.

```
f.select :selector, [[other, things]], {}, { :tabindex => 1 }
```